# Loading a Resource file with XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, embedded-resource, xelement

I'm trying to load an XML file that is an embedded resource.

I'm using the code below and it's returning an error saying the URI is too long.

```
base.document = XElement.Load(RStudio.Properties.Resources.TemplateDOC);
```

Any idea what may be wrong? I'm working with .net Framework 3.5.

Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's trying to use `TemplateDOC` as the *name* of a file. Assuming your resource value is actually the XML itself, you want

```
base.document = XElement.Parse(RStudio.Properties.Resources.TemplateDOC);
```

I suspect that really is what you want - because if it's an embedded resource, there isn't really a filename (or URL) you could give it to load.

If it's were an embedded resource *as a separate file in the assembly*, then you could use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) and then [`XElement.Load(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838544.aspx).